# REST and Many to Many Relationship with a One to Many Relationship

Tags: database, rest, url

My database design has a Many to Many where the joining table has a one to many. This is shown below:

```
Exercise
    ID
    Name
    Templates (Many to Many with Template through TemplateExercise)
    ...

Template
    ID
    Exercises (Many to Many with Exercise through TemplateExercise)
    Name
    ...

TemplateExercise
    """
    Many-to-many relationship for Template and Exercise
    """
    ID
    ExerciseID
    TemplateID
    ExerciseSets (One to Many with ExerciseSet)
    ...

ExerciseSet
    ID
    TemplateExerciseID
    Maximum Rest
    Minimum Rest
    ...
```

Currently, I have following URLS:

**Exercise**

```
/api/exercise [GET]
/api/exercise/id [GET]
```

**Template**

```
/api/template [GET | POST]
/api/template/id [GET | PUT | DELETE]
```

Currently, when performing `PUT /api/template/id`, only the templates attributes are updated, and not it's relationships.

My question is, whats the best way to design the URLS for updating/deleting template exercises and their sets?

I was thinking something like this:

`/api/template/{id}/exercise/ [GET | POST ]` - would retrieve all template exercise instances, and allow for a new template exercise to be created (along with their sets).

`/api/template/{id}/exercise/{id} [GET | DELETE]` - would retrieve a template exercise instance and it's sets, and allow for it to be deleted.

`/api/template/{id}/exercise/{id}/set/ [GET | POST]` - get all sets of a template exercise and allow for new ones to be added.

`/api/template/{id}/exercise/{id}/set/{id} [GET | DELETE | PUT]` - get a single set of a exercise and allow for it to be deleted or updated.

Does this look sensible?

Comment: Why do you think REST has anything to do with relational database design? ;-)

Comment: I dont. I was explaining my database situation. It's not common to have a 'one to many' on a 'many to many' joining table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rest+many+to+many btw. you need something like `/api/template-exercise/` to modify the relationships at least that's the easiest way.